# calendario detepickcer lee fechas en blanco en JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

en JS - Jquery

```
 $("#fecha_programacion_para_seleccionar").click(function () {

       lc_fecha_programacion = $("#fecha_programacion_para_seleccionar").onSelect();
        alert(lc_fecha_programacion);
            $("#fecha_programacion_para_seleccionar").datepicker(
            $.extend({
                firstDay: 1,
                onSelect: function (lc_fecha) {
                    alert('Dentro del Select' + lc_fecha);
                    // var lc_fecha = $("#echa_programacion_para_seleccionar").val();

                }
            })
        );






    });
```

HTML:

```
 <div id="fecha_programacion_para_seleccionar"></div>;
```

El problema es que lee la fecha en blanco, que estoy haciendo mal..

Answer (score 0):

Saludos lo he probado y funciona bien:

```js
function cargarDatePicker(){
      $("#datepicker").datepicker(
            $.extend({
                firstDay: 1,
                onSelect: function (lc_fecha) {
                    alert('Dentro del Select ' + lc_fecha);
                }
            })
        );
}//end function cargarDatePicker
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
 
<div id="datepicker" onclick="cargarDatePicker()";>Click aqui para Seleccionar Fecha</div></p>
 
 
</body>
```

Deberías revisar tu html  para ver si no tienes otros elementos con el mismo "ID" también revisa que estén bien definidas las librerías de **DatePicker** espero te sirva y suerte.

Comment: tengo la version jQuery v2.0.3, pero como se usaria el datepicker?

Comment: la idea de un datepicker es que selecciones la fecha y esta se almacene en un input, pero en tu caso desconosco la razon de usar el div, puedes ver el funcionamiento en la pagina oficial: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/... y tambien su documentacion  y ejemplos..